# Probability proportional to size

Tags: probability, self-study, sampling

Consider the problem of drawing a sample of size $2$ from a finite population of size $20$ . The sampling is done with replacement using probability proportional to size scheme  . The normed size measures $p_1 , p_2 ,  \ldots, p_{20}$ . are given by

$ p_i = \frac{1}{40}  ,  i  =1 ,\ldots,10  $

$p_i = \frac{3}{40} ,  i  =11 ,\ldots,20                      $
   , find the expected no. of distinct units drawn

**attempt**  :

let $X$ denote the no. of distinct units drawn then $X$ denotes the value 
$0 , 1 , 2$ .

Now how to proceed to caculate probabilities , please provide some approach for this question or any alternative suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

There are only two possibility, either they are identical or they are not.

For the probability of being identical, compute$$\sum_{i=1}^{20}P(X_2=i|X_1=i)P(X_1=i)=\sum_{i=1}^{20}P(X_2=i)P(X_1=i)$$

You might like to consider the sum for $i$ from $1$ to $10$ and the sum from $11$ to $20$ separately.

Comment: we need expected no. of distinct units , not identical ,

Comment: If you can compute the probability, you can get the expected value right?